# Reshape Dataframe - Change columns and rows

Tags: r, dataframe, long-integer, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to have the Stations as columns, one column for Station 1, one for Station 2 and one for Station 3.

The days should be in the rows instead, just like this:

```
Date         Day        Station 1      Station 2      Station 3
2000-01-01   Day1          5              15             20
2000-01-01   Day2         4.0            8.8             11.2
2000-01-01   Day3         10              30             40
2000-02-01   Day1         10              NA             25
2000-02-01   Day2         6.4             NA             13.6
2000-02-01   Day3         20              NA             50
2000-03-01   Day1         NA              NA             30
2000-03-01   Day2         NA              NA             16.0
2000-03-01   Day3         NA              NA             60
```

I have used the reshape(df) before, but I dont know how to adapt it to make it work in this case.

Any ideas?

Here is the code of my testframe:

```
x1= c("Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 2", "Station 3", "Station 3", "Station 3")
x2= c("2000-01-01", "2000-02-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-02-01", "2000-03-01")
x3= seq(5, 30, length=6)
x4= seq(4, 16, length=6)
x5= seq(10, 60, length=6) 

testframe = data.frame(Station=x1, Date=x2, Day1=x3, Day2=x4, Day3=x5)
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); testframe %>% 
  gather(Day, value, Day1:Day3) %>% 
  spread(Station, value)`

Comment: `install.packages("tidyverse")` (This is how you install any package that's available on CRAN)

Comment: Thanks! That is working great!! I just found out how to install it. Somehow I tried that, but it didnt work on my first try, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies to Nate, but that is a really bad approach to solving this problem. The correct "reshape2" approach would be either of the following:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(testframe, id.vars = 1:2), Date + variable ~ Station)
recast(testframe, Date + variable ~ Station, id.var = c("Station", "Date"))
```

Both result in the following:

```
#         Date variable Station 1 Station 2 Station 3
# 1 2000-01-01     Day1       5.0      15.0      20.0
# 2 2000-01-01     Day2       4.0       8.8      11.2
# 3 2000-01-01     Day3      10.0      30.0      40.0
# 4 2000-02-01     Day1      10.0        NA      25.0
# 5 2000-02-01     Day2       6.4        NA      13.6
# 6 2000-02-01     Day3      20.0        NA      50.0
# 7 2000-03-01     Day1        NA        NA      30.0
# 8 2000-03-01     Day2        NA        NA      16.0
# 9 2000-03-01     Day3        NA        NA      60.0
```

Alternatively, as suggested by eipi10, you can use the "tidyverse" package too:

```
library(tidyverse)
testframe %>% 
  gather(Day, value, Day1:Day3) %>% 
  spread(Station, value)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested it and its working aswell. But what does the "id.vars = 1:2" mean? What is 1:2?

Comment: @Essi 1:2 are the column numbers. You can use a character vector of the names if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! When I have now Day 1 - Day 31 instead of Day 1 - Day 3, what do I have to change to get it working? I dont get that working at the first solution.

Comment: @Essi, So, are your current columns "Station", "Date", and Day 1 through Day 31? Or are there other columns? The approach should still be the same....